# Nested Object Construction JQ

Tags: json, object, jq

From [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s [Types And Values Documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues):

> ##### Object Construction
>
> The value can be any expression (although you may need to wrap it in parentheses if, for example, it contains colons), which gets applied to the `{}` expression's input (remember, all filters have an input and an output).
>
> ```json
> {foo: .bar}
> ```
>
> [ ... ]
>
> Because that is so common, there's a **shortcut syntax** for it: `{user, title}`.

So given the following example json

```json
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "value": 42,
            "valid": true
        },
        "valid": false
    },
    "valid": false
}
```

If I *only* want the *complete* `foo` object (removing the outer `valid` key), I can get the desired output by using

```
{ foo }
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1WJ_k3UkmG)</sup>

---

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't mention any way to get the same behaviour, but for **deeper** keys, using the example above, getting an output object with just the `.foo.bar` object would look something like:

```
{ "foo": { "bar": .foo.bar } }
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/33H-QnEiR8)</sup>

Which will generate the following (desired) json output:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "value": 42,
      "valid": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** both the outer `valid` and the `.foo.valid` are missing.

---

Is there any short-cut alternative for the above selector to get the same result?

Ideally I'd use something like:

```
{ foo.bar }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Inian. Added another key to make the desired output more clear.

Comment: Does shaving off four characters count as a short-cut?  If so: `{ foo: { bar: .foo.bar } }` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a short-cut alternative, but the path functions can be used for this. This assumes you know the names of the paths beforehand and know they exist

```
jq -n 'setpath( ["foo", "bar"] ; ( inputs | getpath(["foo", "bar"]) ) )'
```

The `setpath/2` function sets the value on the assigned path indicated in the first argument. The value  for the path is set from the original input using `getpath/1`

You could use the `--argjson` to pass the path as an array and use it directly as well.

```
jq -n --argjson p '["foo", "bar"]' 'setpath( $p ; ( inputs | getpath($p) ) )'
```

Comment: Could you please add an online demo? I think [I'm missing something](https://jqplay.org/s/rqzHcMCGY8)?

Comment: Ahh thank you, [it's working fine now](https://jqplay.org/s/w4-IYEUyAy)! I'll give it a go.

Comment: My apologies for letting you respond, had kind of forgotten about this question. Unfortunately, I was hoping for a shorter answer. For now I'll stick with an upvote so another answer might come along. Thanks.

Comment: There can't  be a smaller answer if the tool doesn't support it. :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is (quite literally) a shorter alternative that's also DRYer, though I don't think it's any clearer:

```
{foo} | .foo |= {bar}
```